# Undefined reference to SOME_SIGNAL_NAME

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I have some signal in my class, is called `requestFinished`.
Also i have slot `_finished`, which should activate that signal.
But i have error `undefined reference to MY_SIGNAL`.
Here is `_finished`:

```
void VK::_finished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << (QString) reply->readAll();
    } else {
        QString json(reply->readAll());
        VKResponse *response = new VKResponse(json);
        VKError *error = new VKError(json);
        VKAnswer *answer = new VKAnswer(error, response);
        emit requestFinished(answer);
    }
}
```

Here is class `VK`:

```
class VK {
    public:
        VK(QString token);
        void request(QString method, std::map<QString, QString> data);
        ~VK();

    private:
        QString token;

    private slots:
        void _finished(QNetworkReply *reply);

    signals:
        void requestFinished(VKAnswer *answer);
};
```

As you can see, it contains method `requestFinished` in signals. What is my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is missing `Q_OBJECT` macro in `VK` class declaration.

Comment: I removed it, because i get error `undefined reference to 'vtable for VK'` with it. Google said me it is problem with virtual methods, but i haven't them. //sorry for my english

Comment: `VK` must also be a subclass of `QObject` for singals/slots to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VK class needs to publicly inherit QObject and include Q_OBJECT as the first thing:

```
class VK: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        VK(QString token);
        void request(QString method, std::map<QString, QString> data);
        virtual ~VK();

    private:
        QString token;

    private slots:
        void _finished(QNetworkReply *reply);

    signals:
        void requestFinished(VKAnswer *answer);
};
```

you will then need to ensure the moc is run against that (usually this is automatic in QtCreator)

Comment: Thanks for advice. I added `Q_OBJECT`, and inherited class from `QObject`. Now i have error `undefined reference to 'vtable for VK'`. //upd: solved. I added `virtual` to my destructor and now all working fine. Thanks!